# To what Sobolev space does this function belong to?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, distribution-theory

I am given this function:
$$f(x) = e^{- \sqrt{|x|}}$$

and I want to find $k\in \mathbb{N}, \ p \ge 1$ such that $f \in W^{kp} (\mathbb{R})= \{ f \in L^p (\mathbb{R}) \ | \ \forall \alpha \le k: \ D^{\alpha} f_w \in L^p (\mathbb{R}) \}$

Here $D^{\alpha} f_w$ is the $\alpha$-th weak derivative of $f$.

$f'_w = h$ such that $\forall \varphi \in C^{\infty}_0 : \int f(x) \varphi'(x) dx = - \int h(x) \varphi(x) dx$

So what I do is I try to find the first weak derivative of $f$.
Then I establish for what $p$ : $f'_w \in L^p$.

Then I would find $f''_w$ and find the proper $p$ by integrating $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f''_w(t)|^p dt$$

And I would continue this up until I get a function which isn't weakly differentiable.

And my problem is in integrating:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \varphi'(x) dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{- \sqrt{|x|}} \varphi'(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{- \sqrt{-x}} \varphi'(x) dx + \int_0^{\infty} e^{- \sqrt{x}} \varphi'(x) dx$$

$$= -\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{e^{- \sqrt{-x}}}{2 \sqrt{-x}} \varphi(x) dx - \int_0^{\infty} \frac{-e^{- \sqrt{x}}}{2 \sqrt{x}} \varphi(x) dx$$

So it appears that $$f'_w(x) = -sgn(x) \cdot \frac{e^{- \sqrt{|x|}}}{2 \sqrt{|x|}}$$

Is that correct so far?

Comment: Yes, it is correct, but to make things more clear, you should include explicitly the boundary terms (at $x=0$) coming from the integration by parts.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre I see, I know that those terms will be zero, but I will remember to write them explicitly in the future. Thank you. I have one more question though. For $k=1, f'_w \in L^p$ for all $p \ge 1$. Is that right?

Comment: @JuliánAguirre I also computed the second weak derivative and it seems I can go on differentiating this function on and on. While integrating by parts as above, only plugging $f'_w$ in place of $f$ I get this http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx+%28e^{-\sqrt{-x}}%29%2F%282+\sqrt{-x}%29 for x<0. It looks quite smooth

Comment: Could this function belong to $W^{kp}$ for all $k$ and $p$?

Comment: Because the singularity at $x=0$,  $f'_w\in L^p$ for $1\le p<2$. As to $f''_w$, it will have a Dirac's $\delta$ at $x=0$, coming from the jump in $f'_w$.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Great, thanks! I missed the fact that we have $x$ in the denominator and hence singularity at zero. Thank you!